# Configuring Brother Scan ADS-1600W

Tags: drivers, configuration, scanner

I'm new in the Ubuntu universe and I have a problem in configuring my scan. I installed the driver brscan4 and the scan key tool from Brother but I have no idea how to use the tool to configure the scan (indicate the destination folder for the scanned documents).
In fact, I do not know where I can access the tool or how I can start it.
Thanks for any idea.
I use Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: Please run the installer again and see if an error similar to this comes up: ERROR: libusb-0.1 is required

Comment: Thank you for the hint, I ran the installer again and he confirmed that everything was installed correctly

Answer (score 0):

so Brother provide an FAQ that details several extra steps 
http://support.brother.com/g/s/id/linux/en/faq_scn.html?c=us_ot&lang=en&redirect=on

1) http://support.brother.com/g/s/id/linux/en/faq_scn.html?c=us_ot&lang=en&redirect=on#f00107

```
install libusb-0.1-4 `sudo sudo apt install libusb-0.1-4
```

2) http://support.brother.com/g/s/id/linux/en/faq_scn.html?c=us_ot&lang=en&redirect=on#f00101 copy some files

```
sudo cp /usr/lib64/sane/libsane-brother4.so.1.0.7 /usr/lib/sane
sudo cp /usr/lib64/sane/libsane-brother4.so /usr/lib/sane
sudo cp /usr/lib64/sane/libsane-brother4.so.1 /usr/lib/sane
```

3) download and install the file that sets the udev rule http://support.brother.com/g/s/id/linux/en/instruction_scn1c.html?c=us_ot&lang=en&redirect=on#u13.04